# If $U$ and $V$ are disjoint , prove that $ \operatorname{Int} (\operatorname{Cl}U) $ and $\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(V) $ are disjoint sets.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $ U,V \subset X$ open subsets of $X$. If $U$ and $V$ are disjoint , prove that  $ \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}U) $ and $\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(V) $ are disjoint sets.

I tried by contradiction but got nowhere. I supposed that there exists $ x \in \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}U) \cap \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(V) $ , so then there exist base elements ( or open sets too ) $B1,B2 $ so that $ x \in B1 \subset \operatorname{Cl}U $ and  $ x \in B2 \subset \operatorname{Cl}V $. I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is in the intersection of these two sets. Then $x \in cl(V)$. Hence the neighborghood $Int(cl(U))$ of $x$ must intersect $V$. But $U \subset V^{c}$  ( $V^{c}$ denoting the complement of $V$) and $V^{c}$ is closed  so $\overset {-} U \subset V^{c}$. This implies $Int(cl(U) \subset V^{c}$. we have arrived at a  contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Assume x in int cl U $\cap\ $ int cl V.
x in int cl U and x in cl V.
Exists a in int cl U $\cap\ $ V.
a in V and a in cl U.
Exists b in U $\cap\ $ V.